# 100% width/height absolute parent with padding

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a container that fills up it's parent with some padding like you see in the blow snippet. Right now the only way I could figure out how to accomplish this is with `calc()`. And since `calc` technically has a better browser support then `flex`, I'd like to stay away from that.

Can anyone see a way to accomplish this without javascript and with calc()?

Assume that all width's are percentages.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}

.box {
  position:relative;
  margin:5px;
}

.halfBox {
  padding-bottom:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.fullBox {
  padding-bottom:50%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.content {
  font-size:12px;
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  position:absolute;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  height:calc(100% - 20px);
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:0">
  <div style="width:200px;display:inline-block;">
    <div class="halfBox box">
      <div class="content">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:400px;display:inline-block;">
    <div class="fullBox box">
      <div class="content">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `top`/`left` like you did and `right`/`bottom`

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}

.box {
  position:relative;
  margin:5px;
}

.halfBox {
  padding-bottom:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.fullBox {
  padding-bottom:50%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.content {
  font-size:12px;
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:0">
  <div style="width:200px;display:inline-block;">
    <div class="halfBox box">
      <div class="content">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:400px;display:inline-block;">
    <div class="fullBox box">
      <div class="content">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also consider margin too:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}

.box {
  position:relative;
  margin:5px;
}

.halfBox {
  padding-bottom:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.fullBox {
  padding-bottom:50%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.content {
  font-size:12px;
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:0">
  <div style="width:200px;display:inline-block;">
    <div class="halfBox box">
      <div class="content">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:400px;display:inline-block;">
    <div class="fullBox box">
      <div class="content">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Yea that was obvious. Thanks for this!